# Searching a string for numbers including decimals in VBA

Tags: string, excel, vba, converters

So I'm working on a project that has inputs from a fairly clunky database that I have zero control over what type of data it gives me.  It basically gives me a string that has numbers in it including decimals.

"***take 0.5 Tab*** by mouth 2 times daily."

Whenever it says tab I want to grab the number before tab and convert it to double format.  I know how to use cdbl to convert it once I have the string "0.5" but how I get just that string is kind of difficult since InStr only searches left to right.  My thought was to use InStr to find the space before the number that comes before the word "tab" but I'm having trouble figuring out how to code it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Another thought I had was to split using the " " as a delimiter but I still can't get my mind around how to find the value before "tab" or "tabs".

Comment: Do the values contain multiple "."? 
You could use " " and take the previous array element. I am going to update my answer.

Comment: It is possible for there to be multiple "." in the string.  The strings I am getting from the database are pretty variable in length and format

Comment: Could it be that the number is not right in front of tab as well? For example `taking 2.0 or more Tab" is recommended`. Do you want to verify that the chunk in front of tab is a certain [number-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type#Numeric_types) so `2.0` (float) instead of just `2` (integer)?

Comment: The methods listed here, including the answers below can be implemented within the database. I would suggest doing it there rather than bringing it into Excel.

Answer (score 6):

`InStrRev` searches right to left.  Alternatively, you can use `StrReverse` and work with the output, but I would use `VBScript.Regexp`:

```
Dim text As String
text = "take 0.5 Tab by mouth 2 times daily"

Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")

regex.Global = True
regex.Pattern = "[\d\.]+(?=\sTab)"

Dim test As Object
Set test = regex.Execute(text)
MsgBox (test(0).Value)
```

Comment: +1 nicely done Worth adding a regexp `test` prior to the `execute`

Answer (score 1):

#### Update using Tab as relevant indicator

Assuming that `Tab` is the relevant indicator you could do the follwing:

```
Sub ExtractElement()
    ' column 4 and row 6 contains the text "take 0.5 Tab by mouth 2 times daily"
    s = Cells(6, 4).Value
    ' split text into array for each space
    sAr = Split(s, " ")
    ' iterate over each element of array  
    For i = 0 To UBound(sAr) - 1
        ' if the array element "Tab" is reached 
        If  sAr(i) = "Tab" Then 
            ' write the previous array element into the next column
            Cells(6, 5).Value = sAr(i-1)
        End If        
    Next    
End Sub
```

Beware that each word is really seperated by a " ". I copied your text and noticed that "Tab by" was not seperated.

```
Sub ExtractCharCode()

    s = Cells(7, 4).Value
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Cells(i, 8).Value = Mid(s, i, 1)
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

#### Update using a variation of [the answer from user matzone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492500/searching-a-string-for-numbers-including-decimals-in-vba/17493388?noredirect=1#17493388)

Instead of passing a range into the function from matzone i would only pass the Value and add a trim to it

```
Public Function TakeBeforeTab2(s As String) As String
    s = Mid(s, 1, InStr(UCase(s), "TAB") - 1)
    TakeBeforeTab2 = Trim(Mid(s, InStr(s, " ") + 1))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

To get `"0.5"` from `"take 0.5 Tab by mouth 2 times daily."`

```
Public Function TakeBeforeTab(r As Range) As String
Dim s As String

s = r.Value
s = Mid(s, 1, InStr(UCase(s), "TAB") - 2)
TakeBeforeTab = Mid(s, InStr(s, " ") + 1)

End Function
```

Comment: You could add a trim() otherwise it returns "0.5 "

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree .. trim() in which line ? .. the last mid() should remove "take" word ..

Comment: In my test was still a space at the end - what happens if you change it to `TakeBeforeTab = "_"+Mid(s, InStr(s, " ") + 1)+"_"` does it contain a following space?
Upvote for elegant solution.

Comment: I put the trim at the last line of your function - see my update of my answer