# How to extract a decimal number in a string?

Tags: string, excel, vba

I want to extract (or seperate) a decimal number from a `string`. Like:

> width(6.15)

Here I just want to keep the decimal number.

```
Sub first_try()

Dim a, b
a = "width(5.55)"
For i = 1 To Len(a)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(a, i, 1)) Then
        b = b & Mid(a, i, 1)
    End If
Next i

'Debug.Print b

End Sub
```

But in this case, I can only keep the number (like 555 for my code) but not the decimal number. And the string is not always like Width(5.55), there is no regular to follow. So if you've got some idea, please give me some advices. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching a string for numbers including decimals in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492500/searching-a-string-for-numbers-including-decimals-in-vba)

Comment: "there is no regular to follow". There *must* be some rule or other, else this problem is not solvable.

Comment: Can you just add `Or Mid(a, i, 1) = "." ` to your `if-statement`?

Comment: Thank you all, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492500/searching-a-string-for-numbers-including-decimals-in-vba) is really helpful. And "there is no regular to follow" because I'm working on a report of quality test, the number could be in brackets or without brackets, and after the decimal point, the number is varing with the different type of test.

Comment: @MattCremeens Good idea... Why I didn't think about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way:

```
Sub first_try()

Dim a, b
Dim i As Long
a = "width(5.55)"
For i = 1 To Len(a)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(a, i, 1)) Then
        b = Val(Mid(a, i))
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Debug.Print b

End Sub
```

given the information you have provided. If you need to allow for negative numbers that should be a simple change.

Comment: Thank you! It works well. But I have a question, I don't quiet understand `If IsNumeric(Mid(a, i, 1)) Then`. We check every number (can I say that?) in the String, and if it is a number, then we put the rest of string into b. So I think it would left only the last number in b, but actually it is not? Could you explain it a little bit for me?

Comment: It checks each character in turn, one by one. If the character is a number, the code uses Val on the rest of the string. Val will return everything up to the first thing it doesn't recognise as part of a number (it will recognise commas and decimal points). At that point the code exits the loop and doesn't continue testing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get **numerals** and the decimal point:

```
Sub first_try()

Dim a, b
a = "width(5.55)"
For i = 1 To Len(a)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(a, i, 1)) Or Mid(a, i, 1) = "." Then
        b = b & Mid(a, i, 1)
    End If
Next i

Debug.Print b

End Sub
```

Comment: Haha that's a good method! Thank you! Why I just didn't get this idea!

Comment: But if the number is really large, like 5,555 (even it's not possible in my case, but that could have some mistakes...) and this method fails.